# Create HTTPS api in nodejs and test it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm creating an api that should run on https.  I create the server this way:

```
//...
var app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());

// do config, like app.use(express.bodyParser());, etc

var myController = require('../app/controllers/myController');  
app.get('/myApi/', myController.someFunction);

var useHTTPS = true;

if (useHTTPS) {
    var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./config/key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./config/cert.pem')
    };
    var port = 3443;
    https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
    console.log('started HTTPS on port ' + port);
} else {
    var port = 3000;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('started HTTP on port ' + port);
}

module.exports = app;
```

With this, I am able to access the api via curl.  Then I install mocha and supertest and try this in a new ./test/test.js file, copied from a couple examples...

```
var assert = require('assert');    
var request = require('supertest')
  , express = require('express');

var app = express();

describe('GET /myApi', function(){
  it('respond with json', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/myApi/')
      .expect(200, done);
  })
})
```

But this test always fails, never reaching a `console.log()` in my controller.  It always responds like this, whether I use HTTP or HTTPS....

> 1) GET /myApi respond with json:
>        Error: expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"
>        at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:232:12)

**Am I creating the express https app incorrectly?  Or am I accessing it incorrectly in the test file?**

I thought that simply saying `app = express();` in the test file looked wrong, but when I try to get the "real" app from app.js, like this...

```
// in ./test/test.js
var app = require("../app.js");
```

I get a different error saying that the port is already in use...

> Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3443

Which I guess makes sense.  I'm stuck.  Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: It's usually better to run your server with regular http and setup an http server like nginx or apache (configured with an ssl) in front of your app server. You would then proxy all requests from the secure server to the app server. With this setup, you don't need to worry about testing that your connection is encrypted in your application layer. Instead just test the functionality as you would normally do.

Comment: `/myApi` is not the same as `/myApi/` (note the trailing `/`).

Comment: Thanks @jcaron, when I fix the route (edited) and take Seth's idea to use http, I still get the 404 Not Found.  Would sure appreciate any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the a minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const controller = require("./controller");

const useHTTPS = true;
const app = express();
app.get("/api/", controller.someFunction);

let server;
if (useHTTPS) {
  const https = require("https");
  const fs = require("fs");
  const path = require("path");

  const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./config/key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./config/cert.pem")),
  };
  const port = 3443;
  server = https.createServer(options, app);
  server.listen(port);
  console.log("started HTTPS on port " + port);
} else {
  const port = 3000;
  server = app.listen(port);
  console.log("started HTTP on port " + port);
}

module.exports = server;
```

`controller.js`:

```js
function someFunction(req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
}

module.exports = {
  someFunction,
};
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("./app");

describe("GET /api", function() {
  after((done) => {
    app.close(done);
  });
  it("respond with json", function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get("/api/")
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
started HTTPS on port 3443


  GET /api
    ✓ respond with json


  1 passing (37ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |    88.89 |       50 |      100 |    88.89 |                   |
 app.js        |    83.33 |       50 |      100 |    83.33 |          23,24,25 |
 app.test.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 controller.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

The error `Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3443` means the address is already in use.

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/35559645

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a baseline Express application:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("howdy!");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening");
});
```

**EADDRINUSE** is a common error, it means you have another running web server on your port. You can go find that other running web server and stop it or alternatively you can change your port to another number. Once you make that change, save the file you should see the error go away.

Additionally, Express only cares about the **Path:**`'/myApi/'` and the **Method:**`'GET'`, so I would check to see if I put that together correctly. With that said, your test can be confusing as your are `describe('GET /myApi'` but your **Path** is actually `/myApi/`, they are not the same thing and if you are not careful your test will fail as a result of that detail.

So if the router does not see the correct incoming **Path**, it will not run the function, the callback function you wrote.